# How to show or hide locality in google maps using zoom level?

Tags: google-maps

I want to show or hide the locality on my map depending on the zoom level.

I'm asking if it's possible in the mapOptions settings.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I add a listener for 'zoom_changed' event.
Then I change the options.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
  if (map.getZoom() >= 9) {
    map.setOptions({
      styles: mapStylesLocality
    });
  }
  else {
    map.setOptions({
      styles: mapStyles
    });
  }
});
```